# How to add a column in pandas with values taken from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, df1 and df2.
df1 has 2 columns 'Name' and 'K'.
df2 has 3 columns 'A', 'B', 'C'

The values of the column B are the same values of df1 'Name'. But now I need to add the column K.

So I tried

```
for t in range(len(df1)):
        whichvalue=t
        a=df1.iloc[whichvalue,:]
        Name=a['Name']

        knownetf=df2['B'].value_counts()[Name]
        etfs.loc(df2['B']==Name)['K']=a['K']
```

But this does not seem to work
What is a good pythonic way of doing it?

(I am new to Pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply assign as follows:

```
s = df1.set_index('Name')['K']
df2['K'] = df2['B'].map(s)
```

The reason this works is because `pd.Series.map` accepts a series as an input, so we use `s` in a dictionary-like fashion to map values of 'K' from `df1`.

Of course, you should check first that the mapping is defined uniquely by 'Name' in `df1`.

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure what you mean by "check first that the mapping is defined uniquely by 'Name' in df1". The term "Name" appears multiple times, in multiple rows, and they all should get the same K.

Comment: What I mean is that one 'Name' cannot map to 2 K's. But you mention that's never the case, so you will be fine.